# params['description'] not showing on facebook photo post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a FB app that posts photos to FB. We are passing a customer generated comment, but we want to post a description from the company that hosts the site. We have another version where we use the params['description'] property to create the info on the post, just below the photo.  However, on this app, whatever we pass to description is lost and not shown.

Anyone have any ideas on this?
Thanks

Comment: There is no `description` parameter mentioned in the creating photos section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Creating

Comment: We are actually using the "FB.api('/me/feed', 'post'" method, which does include a description param.